# GPS SOS Signal Device

Tags: gps, transmitter

Is there a way to send GPS coordinates from one device to another, without the use of any kind of cell service?

What I'm attempting to design is a device that connect to a motorcycles' tip-over sensor, that can send some sort of SOS message to a pre-determined contact (phone number, email address, web server, etc) in the event of a crash. The problem is that often times, the places we motorcyclists ride is not within cell reception. I've found a lot of information on how to build GPS tracking devices, but they seem to all require an internet connection or cell service. So it'll have to be a satellite transmission of some sort, I think.

Comment: Amateur radio / APRS? Using some encoding methods you can get half way round the world from a 5w walkie talkie, albeit at a few characters a minute.

Answer (score 3):

GPS itself can only receive.  If a signal needs to be sent, then there has to be a separate communication sub-system.

A close thing for what you're describing is a product called [Spot Locator](http://www.findmespot.com/en/).  It has a satellite modem for Globalstar.  Check if they have a variant with an input for an external sensor.

Comment: I did run across the Spot when doing my research, I like the concept, but I don't want to use it because it would drive cost through the roof.

Comment: That is about your only option for total coverage.  Some places seen to rent them.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon_station